# Adding text in integer field for label using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am labeling mile points along several different lines in QGIS 3.2. For the labels I am using a field that is just integers so the labels are 1, 2, 3, etc but I would like to add some text so that that for one line it'd say, for example A1, A2, etc.

Is there a function to add the text characters in either the field/a new field or in the label styling window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is! With string concatenation `||` you can make label with custom strings, or with values from other fields. In *Label with* field write expression like this:

`'A'||your_field`

or use expression builder [image]

example:
[image]

Comment: You beat me to it.  One thing to add, is if you want a permanent field with values like A1, A2, etc, you can use the Field Calculator to create a text field using the same expression.